# Consuming an async .net WebApi from Angular 2+ and Swagger

Tags: angular, async-await, task, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I am starting on the Angular 2+ (v8) journey and have run into a few questions on best practice to consume async c# WebApi functions. Questions at the end:

In my example WebApi (please note this will in future call a repository in an async way but doesn't currently for brevity) I have the following function:

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Task<IEnumerable<SearchResult>>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery]string searchText, [FromQuery]int pageSize = 10, [FromQuery]int pageIndex = 0)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
  {
    return BadRequest();
  }

  //Call a repository here and return a result
  var searchResults = new List<SearchResult>()
  {
    new SearchResult()
    {
      SearchResultType = SearchResultType.Law, Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
      Title = "A boring title",
      Description = "A boring decription"
    },
    new SearchResult()
    {
      SearchResultType = SearchResultType.Law, Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
      Title = "An interesting title",
      Description = "An exciting description"
    },
  };

  return Ok(await Task.FromResult(searchResults.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(searchText))));
}
```

This returns `Task<IActionResult>` and I have used the Swagger Decorator to say the route returns `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Task<IEnumerable<SearchResult>>)` . However in swagger example response then expects a Task Model :

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "searchResultType": "Law",
      "id": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "description": "string"
    }
  ],
  "id": 0,
  "exception": {},
  "status": "Created",
  "isCanceled": true,
  "isCompleted": true,
  "isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
  "creationOptions": "None",
  "asyncState": {},
  "isFaulted": true
}
```

Where as the actual response is :

```
[
  {
    "searchResultType": 1,
    "id": "0ba4e4ef-37fd-4a76-98ed-4fad64d26b1b",
    "title": "A boring title",
    "description": "A boring description."
  },
  {
    "searchResultType": 1,
    "id": "e8c7e39d-cca6-43b2-90be-87537a4a0b8e",
    "title": "An exciting title",
    "description": "An exciting description."
  }
]
```

In Angular 8 my service consuming this is:

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  search(
    filter: { searchTerm: string } = { searchTerm: "" },
    page = 1
  ): Observable<ISearchResult[]> {
    return this.http.get<ISearchResult[]>("api/v1/Search?searchText=" + filter.searchTerm);
  }
}
```

So the questions:

1. Should the `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Task<IEnumerable<SearchResult>>)` really be `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<SearchResult>)` ?
2. Will a `Task<>` ever be returned to a client ?

I ask this because I initially forgot to `await` the return value in the api and the Task model was actually returned to the Angular client and then in the Angular service I had to use the following to get the result which is messy:

```
  return this.http.get<ISearchResult[]>("api/v1/Search?searchText=" + filter.searchTerm)
 .pipe(
   map((res:ISearchResult[]) => res.result)
 );
```

3. Am I doing this the right way ? Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You need to use `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<SearchResult>)`. You don't need to add `Task` here, just specify the exact type your are returning. Therefore your return can simply be:
2. No. The only way you can return a task is if you explicitly return a task. For example, take the following method:

   `[HttpGet("test")]
   [ProducesResponseType(typeof(Task<string>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
   public Task Get()
   {
       return Task.FromResult("snoop");
   }`

That will return you a task, but if your method is marked async, then the return type will always be of type `Task` or `Task<type>`, and the compiler will complain if you don't await, or you return anything but a `Task`.

3. You don't need to map the response. `result` doesn't even exist on your return data. You can simply have:

   `return this.http.get<ISearchResult[]>("api/v1/Search?searchText=" + filter.searchTerm);`

Which will return you an observable of `ISearchResult[]`.

Comment: Apologies, I thought my example api was self explanatory, but obviously not! It was my intention to speak to a repository or some other source in an async manner . I will amend the question

Comment: Thanks. I suppose what confuses me is the Webapi function return type of "public async Task<IActionResult>" which to me says this function will return a Task type-of IActionResult. However you are saying this is never returned to the client unless explicitly asked to. Need to read up more about it.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) would be a good starting point.